# Ubuntu 17.10 no internet

Tags: networking, 17.10

I just upgraded to ubuntu 17.10 and something weird is going on

- I cannot connect to internet *
- if I connect with VPN through another country, then I have internet *

Of course, everything is going fine with my ISP and can connect with other devices. It all happens after upgrade and never used a proxy.

If anyone can help, is welcome.

Thank you

Comment: If you can connect to a VPN you definately have access to the internet, For me, it sounds like a DNS issue. Which DNS Server is configured? Maybe override that in the network's settings. Try `ping 1.1.1.1`.

Comment: wireless or wired connection does not matter, same results, ping 1.1.1.1 gets packets

Comment: Try [this](https://pchelp.ricmedia.com/set-custom-dns-servers-linux-network-manager-resolv-conf/) (Section: Set custom DNS servers on Linux with Network Manager) and see if it helps.

Comment: weird, ping and vpn internet work, normal internet and email not

Comment: found the solution amigos                                                                                                     sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf                                                                                          sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf